# Add watermark-overlay with -filter_complex to multiple outputs (dash)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating a set of files for DASH (without audio) with:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov"
 -y
 -keyint_min 100 -g 100
 -sc_threshold 0
 -c:v libx264
 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -map v:0 -s:0 320x180 -b:v:0 681.125k -maxrate:0 681.125k -bufsize:0 340.5625k
 -map v:0 -s:1 640x360 -b:v:1 2724.5k -maxrate:1 2724.5k -bufsize:1 1362.25k
 -map v:0 -s:2 1280x720 -b:v:2 5449k -maxrate:2 5449k -bufsize:2 2724.5k
 -map v:0 -s:3 1920x1080 -b:v:3 10898k -maxrate:3 10898k -bufsize:3 5449k
 -init_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
 -media_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1
 -seg_duration 4 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v"
 -f dash "myname.mpd"
```

Now I want to add a watermark. How is it done? I tried something like:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov"
 -y
 -i "watermark.png" // Added
 -filter_complex "overlay=24:960" // Added
 -keyint_min 100 -g 100
 -sc_threshold 0
 -c:v libx264
 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -map v:0 -s:0 320x180 -b:v:0 681.125k -maxrate:0 681.125k -bufsize:0 340.5625k
 -map v:0 -s:1 640x360 -b:v:1 2724.5k -maxrate:1 2724.5k -bufsize:1 1362.25k
 -map v:0 -s:2 1280x720 -b:v:2 5449k -maxrate:2 5449k -bufsize:2 2724.5k
 -map v:0 -s:3 1920x1080 -b:v:3 10898k -maxrate:3 10898k -bufsize:3 5449k
 -init_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
 -media_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1
 -seg_duration 4 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v"
 -f dash "myname.mpd"
```

But this results in only getting the 180p-Version of the video. How can I still get all versions of the video with the overlay?

Added:
I tried as well:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov"
 -y
 -i "watermark.png"
 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=24:960[out0][out1][out2][out3]"
 -keyint_min 100 -g 100
 -sc_threshold 0
 -c:v libx264
 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -map "[out0]" -s:0 320x180 -b:v:0 681.125k -maxrate:0 681.125k -bufsize:0 340.5625k
 -map "[out1]" -s:1 640x360 -b:v:1 2724.5k -maxrate:1 2724.5k -bufsize:1 1362.25k
 -map "[out2]" -s:2 1280x720 -b:v:2 5449k -maxrate:2 5449k -bufsize:2 2724.5k
 -map "[out3]" -s:3 1920x1080 -b:v:3 10898k -maxrate:3 10898k -bufsize:3 5449k
 -init_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
 -media_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1
 -seg_duration 4 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v"
 -f dash "myname.mpd"
```

which results in the error:
No output pad can be associated to link label 'out1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [split filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit):

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov"
 -y
 -i "watermark.png"
 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=24:960,format=yuv420p,split=4[out0][out1][out2][out3]"
 -keyint_min 100 -g 100
 -sc_threshold 0
 -c:v libx264
 -map "[out0]" -s:0 320x180 -b:v:0 681.125k -maxrate:0 681.125k -bufsize:0 340.5625k
 -map "[out1]" -s:1 640x360 -b:v:1 2724.5k -maxrate:1 2724.5k -bufsize:1 1362.25k
 -map "[out2]" -s:2 1280x720 -b:v:2 5449k -maxrate:2 5449k -bufsize:2 2724.5k
 -map "[out3]" -s:3 1920x1080 -b:v:3 10898k -maxrate:3 10898k -bufsize:3 5449k
 -init_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
 -media_seg_name "myname_$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1
 -seg_duration 4 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v"
 -f dash "myname.mpd"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! This was really driving me crazy...